# English equivalents of Slovak saying

Tags: expressions, idioms, popular-refrains, proverbs, phraseology

Is there an English equivalent of the Slovak saying:

> Someone else's wounds don't bleed

?

This is literal translation of a saying, meaning "someone else's loss doesn't bother me".

Comment: Hello, Jane. I've gone ahead and removed 4 of your questions. Do ask them separately. Also, please include the research you have done. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

***No skin off my nose.*** -- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_skin_off_one%27s_nose)

> (idiomatic) No harm to one.
>   *You can be as critical of them as you like. It's no skin off my nose.*

Comment: updated question... and your answer accordingly.

Comment: Lee, just to explain NVZ's actions, posts are limited to a single question. Thus, multiple questions require multiple posts. It's good practice not to answer a multi-part question with a multi-part answer, which is why NVZ edited the question and answer to be acceptable :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly exact match...

> It's easy to sleep on another man's wounds

Apparently this is an Hiberno-English proverb, although I've only heard it in other dialects.

There doesn't seem to be much info online about its origins, but someone did base a book title on it:

https://www.irishcentral.com/opinion/others/ernie-o-malley-remembering-the-renaissance-man-of-the-irish-revolution-on-his-120th-birthday

Comment: I'd have to say this did originate as an Irish/Gaelic proverb. I'm not sure this would be a fit as a suggested English equivalent, seeing as there isn't much proof of it being used widely in English, aside from that one book. [See this related Meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/can-i-answer-with-translated-proverbs-or-expressions). While it's not exactly like the Meta says, it is a form of translated saying to widely used in English.

Comment: Hi @Hank, do you have any evidence that it originated as a Gaelic proverb? Just curious.

Comment: Nothing substantial. There's very few results regarding it but all of them say it's an old Irish saying, and a couple said it originated in Gaelic. I can't find the Gaelic translation, though. Literally all of the posts online are in reference to the book, which further supports it's lack of use. I'm still searching though.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to be as common as I thought... I heard it a few times and thought it was well-known https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=another+man%27s+wound&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canother%20man%20%27s%20wound%3B%2Cc0